# Unhandled exception in Script

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I wrote a script and i wanted to make it an exe. I decided to use pyinstaller as, I have used it before and it worked properly. Only for me to try to run the exe and it worked till it got a certain part of my script and this error was shown
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIi56.png).
This was the command used in terminal to produce the exe

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w -i II.ico main.py
```

After research, I saw that the `-w` might have been the issue so i ran it again without it and , the same error occured.
Finally, I also tried to move the libraries my project makes use of to the same folder as my exe but, it still did not fix my issue.
any help would be appreciated

This is the piece of code at line 195

```
    bw.write(trace(THISDIR + "/output.jpg", True))
```

and the entire thing is

```
THISDIR = str(Path(__file__).resolve().parent)
bw = open(THISDIR + "/output.svg", "w")
bw.write(trace(THISDIR + "/output.jpg", True))
bw.close()
```

Comment: What is line 195 in your program?'

Comment: 'bw.write(trace(THISDIR + "/output.jpg", True))' its part of this piece of code  THISDIR = str(Path(__file__).resolve().parent)

        bw = open(THISDIR + "/output.svg", "w")
        bw.write(trace(THISDIR + "/output.jpg", True))
        bw.close()

Comment: Please edit that into the original post so it is more legible.

Comment: Hi there, I have now done that